# Async pig job submission

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I am dynamically generating some Pig query in Java and executing the same using PigServer Class. Is there any way in which I can submit the job asynchronously and later poll/hook for job completion? Also, if pig doesn't allow it , can I use Oozie with Java Action to achieve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [fork and join control nodes](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.5_Fork_and_Join_Control_Nodes) in OOZIE to run jobs in parallel.

Executing dynamic code is easy if you just want to change some properties of the Pig script to run (you can use template variables - see the [oozie pig action](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.3_Pig_Action) docs). However if by dynamic you mean dynamically building different code paths then you'll need a custom Java action to write out the pig script to HDFS before calling the pig action.

Answer (score 0):

First post your query properly.The above description is not well explanatory.If you want to run any job asynchronously in java ,you should use Thread programming.There is a good apache framework called "quartz-scheduler" which can do this task.It is open source.Refer this link.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/

Comment: Multi-threading is one approach but I was looking for something more robust wherein the inherent complexity of parallelism is managed by the framework.(Something like a Task Parallel Lib in .NET) Will definitely have a look at the Quartz Scheduler